# Integration of a function should equal the area

Tags: integration

[image]It seems a silly question but I can't see what's wrong

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{T} \int_0^{T/2} \Big(\dfrac{-2V_mt}{T}+V_m \Big)^2dt}
=&\sqrt{\dfrac{2V^2_m}{T} \int_0^{T/2} \Big(\dfrac{4t^2}{T^2}-4t/T+1 \Big)dt}\\
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{2V_m^2}{T}{\int}_0^{\tfrac{T}{2}}\Bigg(\dfrac{4t^2}{T^2}-\dfrac{4t}{T}+1 \Bigg) dt}\\
  & =\sqrt{\dfrac{2V^2_m}{T}  \Bigg( \dfrac{4\Big(\dfrac{T}{2} \Big)^3}{3T^2} - \dfrac{4\Big(\dfrac{T}{2} \Big)^2}{2T} +  \dfrac{T}{2}\Bigg)} = \dfrac{V_m}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}

Now, the answer should be related to the area of the triangle, and hence it should be simply $\sqrt{\frac{1}{T}(\dfrac{1}{2}V^2_mT)}=V_m/\sqrt{2}$, but the answers don't match.

The goal is to find the RMS value

Comment: What is $T$, $V_m$? Which triangle are you talking about? You need to add more information.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, especially wih regards to why you expect the right-hand side to take the form it does, but I've done my best to discuss this is an answer.

Comment: Explain your $\sqrt 3$.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{T}(\dfrac{1}{2}V^2_mT)}=V_m$ can be true only if $V_m=0$ also.

Comment: Is there any chance we're supposed to e.g. integrate the square or square-root of the suggested integrand, due to the amplitude/intensity relation?

Comment: I added all the work that I have done

Comment: You forgot $^2$  in the first and second line of your equation. I can't corrected myself since "it is less than 6 charaters"

Comment: Do you mean in my question or my comment

Comment: In $\sqrt{\dfrac{2V^2_m}{T} \int_0^{T/2} \Big(\dfrac{4t^2}{T^2}-4t/T+1 \Big)dt}$ and $\sqrt{\dfrac{2V_m^2}{T}{\int}_0^{\tfrac{T}{2}}\Bigg(\dfrac{4t^2}{T^2}-\dfrac{4t}{T}+1 \Bigg) dt}$

Comment: this is after you find the square so no ^2 is missing

Comment: Oh you are right @Diana my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand something. The RMS is the square root of the integral of the square of the function.

So your first calculus $$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{T} \int_0^{T/2} \Big(\dfrac{-2V_mt}{T}+V_m \Big)^2dt}
= \dfrac{V_m}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}$$

is correct. But it should not be the area below the curve ! It is the area below the curve of the squared function.

Comment: yes, this is why I calculated the areas as $V^2_mT/2$ and not $V_mT/2$ so the second one is the area of v^2(t) and not v(t)

Comment: Yes but $Vm^2 T/2$ is the area of height $V_m^2$ and of base T. What I am trying to say is that you should not compute the area of a triangle

Comment: The area below $v^2(t)$ is not the area below a triangle

Comment: Thank you, Yes it shouldn't be

Comment: You're welcome, please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The inner integral is $[-V_mt^2/T+V_mt]_0^{T/2}=-V_mT/4+V_mT/2=V_mT/4$, which as expected is the area of a triangle of base $T/2$, height $V_m$. So for $T\ne0$ the surd is $\sqrt{V_m/2}$, which equals the right-hand side for $V_m\in\{0,\,3/2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the equations by $V_m$ and WLOG, $T=2$. Now,

$$\sqrt{\int_0^1(1-t)\,dt}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$ which matches the other formula.

---

The square in the first integral makes a different question.

Comment: Don't we have $\sqrt{\int_0^1(1-t)^2dt}=\frac1{\sqrt3}$ ?

Comment: @EtienneBfx: oops, yes. The OP introduced confusion by late addition of the square, which makes his second solution invalid.

Comment: But this should be to the square if one want to compute RMS.

Comment: @EtienneBfx: I know.